# Error: invalid mode ('rb') when trying to read excel file in Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm a newbie and I've tried all sorts of things that showed up as answers for similar questions including using pandas_reader and nothing seemed to work. When I put in this code in my Python IDE

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Users\Raul\Downloads\research\test.xlsx")
```

and I keep getting this error

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Raul\\Downloads\research\test.xlsx'
```

and they are saved perfectly and everything.
[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help!

PS I have excel 2013 if that makes a difference

Comment: or put your string in triple quotes `"""C:\Users\Raul\Downloads\research\test.x‌​lsx""""`

Comment: @bernie Hmmm I'm not exactly sure what that means being new to this but when I tried that and I got this error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Raul\\Downloads\\research\\test.x\xe2\x80\x8c\xe2\x80\x8blsx'

Comment: @user1767754 That returned the rb error again :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the error: `invalid mode ('rb')`**`or filename`**:`

In this case, it's your filename. Escape your backslashes (or specify a raw string literal), or else python will misinterpret it (`\U`, `\R`, etc) as special characters.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Users\\Raul\\Downloads\\research\\test.xlsx")
```

Comment: That not only worked, but I actually understand your explanation! Many thanks!

Comment: Yes ofcourse. At the time it told me I had to wait 8 more minutes to accept it so I was waiting :)